# how to set a BP on button in SunAwtCanvas in x96dbg

Tags: assembly, debugging, x64dbg, java, patch-reversing

I'm trying to debug a program in x96dbg that I think this is written in Matlab. There is no string related to buttons or something interesting. Then I go to Handles tab to find buttons and set break point.
[image]

But there is no buttons then I can't set break point on any buttons. The program use SunAwtCanvas in order to show forms. Any suggestion?